# angularJS 1.5 nested components

Tags: angularjs, binding, nested, components

I am trying to build a parent view (with a controller) that has a angularjs component. The parent view delivers the data to the component by two way binding (it is a result of an Web-Service, so the data is a JSON Object). A part of the data is again delivered from the component to another nested component. 
Now when I change the data in the nested component by a textfield, following exception occurs:
angular.js:13424 Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'attributDetailDto' used with directive 'catAuswertungsparameterBearbeitung' is non-assignable!

JS of Component

```
    angular.module('catApp').component('catAuswertungsparameterBearbeitung', {
    controller : CatAuswertungsparameterBearbeitungController,
    templateUrl : 'resources/js/konfiguration/auswertungsparameter/catAuswertungsparameterBearbeitung.html',
    bindings : {
    attributDetailDto : '='
    }
});

function CatAuswertungsparameterBearbeitungController($translate) {
    var ctrl = this;
}
```

HTML of component

```
...
<cat-textfeld min=1 max=50 wert="$ctrl.attributDetailDto.bezeichnung"></cat-textfeld>
...
```

JS of nested component cat-textfeld

```
angular.module('catApp').component('catTextfeld', {
    controller : MinMaxTextfeldController,
    templateUrl : 'resources/js/fwk/catTextfeld.html',
    bindings : {
    wert : '=',
    min : '@',
    max : '@'

    }
});

function MinMaxTextfeldController($translate) {
    var ctrl = this;
```

HTML of nested component

```
<input type="text" class="textfeld" name="textfeld" ng-model="$ctrl.wert">
```

Do you have any ideas? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, you couldn't help me because I totally failed in calling the first component.
This didn't work for sure:

```
<cat-auswertungsparameter-bearbeitung attributDetailDto="attributDetailDto"></cat-auswertungsparameter-bearbeitung>
```

Because angular also divides camel-case attributes:

```
<cat-auswertungsparameter-bearbeitung attribut-detail-dto="attributDetailDto"></cat-auswertungsparameter-bearbeitung>
```

sorry for sapping your time

Answer (score 0):

When using `bindings` in Angular 1.5, you are able to declare the binding parameteres as optional, like this: `wert: '=?'`. This way, using the `catAuswertungsparameterBearbeitung` component will not force using all of its bindings attributes.

Comment: this way I can actually type something in the textfeld without an exception, but the attributDetailDto.bezeichnung isn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

a small advice, start using a pattern like this

```
app.component("someComponent", {
    bindings: {
        something: '='
    },
    templateUrl: "app/templates/layer-list-component.html",
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller:  function () {
    var model = this;
   }
});
```

and then

```
<input type="text" class="textfeld" name="textfeld" ng-model="model.wert">
```

to avoid confusion when using the $ symbol

Comment: `$ctrl` is a default name given to the controller since angular 1.5, I see no problem using it.

Comment: there is no problem but as components start to get deeply nested there might be a confusion so its better to have a different name so you can track bindings better